# How do I grab the first character of an object from a passed in prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array(disney) that's being passed in as a prop.

```
[
    {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Mickey",
        "state": "HI",
    },
    {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Minnie",
        "state": "TX",
    }
]
```

How would I grab just the first character of the object `"name" : "Minnie"` in a function that receives this prop?

```
function(props) {
let name = props.disney.name;
```

This grabs all the name objects

```
Mickey
Minnie
```

I tried using a for loop to iterate through the `name` array but its not allowed in a function that takes in a prop and the string method of `charAt(0)` doesn't work since its not a string.

desired outcome:

```
M
M
```

Comment: iterate through array and use `name.charAt(0)`

Comment: "I tried using a for loop to iterate through the name array but its not allowed in a function that takes in a prop" - what exactly do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and bracket notation or [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Mickey",
        "state": "HI",
    },
    {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Minnie",
        "state": "TX",
    }
];
const res = arr.map(({name})=>name[0]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to get the character at specific position.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "14",
    name: "Mickey",
    state: "HI",
  },
  {
    id: "34",
    name: "Minnie",
    state: "TX",
  },
];

const result = arr.map(({ name }) => name.charAt(0));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with a function, im giving you a function.

Use map() with an arrow function.
Use dot notation.
Logged different results for you, depending on what you wanna do with both Inicials.

```js
    const disney = [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "Mickey",
            "state": "HI",
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "name": "Minnie",
            "state": "TX",
        }
    ];

const props = function(arr){
  let name = arr.map(a => a.name[0]);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(...name);
  console.log(name.join(""));
  console.log(name.join(" / "));
}

props(disney);
```